# css : dropdown menu with arrow effect

Tags: html, css

how to create drop-down menu with arrow effect which work in ie8 as well.

what i did i cut the arrow image and wrote the following css code. it works perfectly for firefox and chrome while not working for **ie8**  is there any solution to create such menu that works in ie8 as well.?

```
 .main-navigation li ul:before {
background: url("images/arow.png") no-repeat scroll left center / 100% auto transparent;
content: "";
display: block;
height: 22px;
left: -6px;
position: absolute;
top: -20px;
width: 222px;
z-index: 1;
 }

.main-navigation li ul {
background-color: #000000;border-color: -moz-use-text-color #494949 #494949;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; border-style: none solid solid; border-width: 0 1px 1px;
box-shadow: 0 0 9px 1px rgba(0, 0, 1, 0.75); padding-top: 10px;  width: 212px; }
```

[image: i used this image as arow]

[image: actual output needed]

Comment: Check out these links. There are multiple menu's available. Downnload the source. Read the instruction and use them http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out (pure CSS)

Here is the
[Demo](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/)

And this is the 
[Source](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/)

Works in IE8

Answer (score -1):

also, try to add the following under head session.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

Comment: If the code you write does not work in ie8, then adding this meta tag does not help.

Comment: No, if you use this code, the style will be Compatible with the CSS even IE 10. Are you writing ASP.net application? if not , it doesn't help.

Comment: I do happen to know how Meta-tags work. IE=edge means IE should use the latest (edge) version of its rendering engine. It does not make any difference to the code or compatibility with the code. If the client is using ie6 or ie7 and if you use CSS3 then this Meta tag does not make one differnce whatsoever

Comment: Check this amazing link to learn more about meta tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge

Comment: In case of IE 6, 7 , it is another question, the CSS3 may not work properly.

Comment: Forget it. I give up. Read the question. read your answer and see if it applies. If you feel it does than im an idiot

Comment: Some styles IE does differently, try it yourself and you have to modify some where of the CSS.

Answer (score -3):

Add this meta tag in between your `<head>` tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Meta-tags? OP is asking for a CSS menu thats will work in IE8. Not for meta-tags. This meta tags does not serve the purpose